# Syntax coloring of own types in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

How can I get Visual Studio to highlight my own class types?
This works fine for C# but not for C++...

Comment: Thanks Jen. I've been spoiled at home with various IDEs and web programming but my visual c++ at work was painful to read through

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For those running Visual Studio 2010 [Highlighterr](http://highlighterr.codeplex.com/) may fit your needs. It's also in the MSDN Visual Studio Gallery. It leverages the improved C++ IntelliSense in 2010.

It makes you set special highlighters in Environment -> Fonts and Colors for the types it detects, but overall it works quite well from what I've seen.

Comment: Wonderful tool.  Colors C++ language elements that MS forgot.  Cost==0.  +1.

Comment: Definitely worth it! Now I can actually use the IDE. Hehe

Comment: Finally! I've been looking into this issue for over a month now, but all I get is Visual Assist X and ReSharper, when I only want some nice colors for my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

you can use [***viusal-assist***](http://www.wholetomato.com/) or [***Re-sharper***](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)

both have setting for your syntax highlightin in `C#` and `C++`

and do extra work such as make optional short key on IDE for you.

> - Develop new code faster with fewer errors.
> - Quickly understand existing code.
> - Refactor existing code making it easier to read and cheaper to
>     maintain.
> - Eliminate time spent searching by allowing instant navigation to any
>     file, symbol or reference.

Comment: If reshaper highlights any syntax in c++ that would be entirely a side-effect. It's not meant to be used with C++, sure you can open a C++ solution/project, if you already have it. However, why would you recommend this product? I wouldn't pay any money for full-blown resharper (it's a great product by the way) just to get some syntax highlighting in C++ - maybe. Now, I'm not going to down vote it or anything like that, just because you've mentioned visual-assist (albeit misspelled).

Answer (score 6):

[MSDN: Defining Keywords in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Install [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/). IIRC, you can download and test it for 30 days.

Beware, though. It's quite addictive. Out of 20 Windows developers I have seen testing this, 18 had their management buy it. `:)`