# Why are user types not highlighted in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, syntax-highlighting, usertype

I would like to have Visual Studio highlight the names of my own classes in the text editor.

I have selected a color under `User Types` in `Options > Fonts & Colors` -- but strangely, this only works for Visual C# but not Visual C++.

Any ideas what's going on?

EDIT: I received some great tips regarding 3rd party tools in response to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386674/syntax-coloring-of-own-types-in-visual-studio-c), but no answer as to why Visual Studio wouldn't provide this capability, or how to properly set it up.

Comment: You have asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386674/syntax-coloring-of-own-types-in-visual-studio-c.

Comment: I received some great tips re 3rd party tools, but not an answer to my actual question, so I clarified it and re-posted it

Comment: The VS authors seem to care more about C# than C++ these days.  I'd love to have right-click -> extract function, etc, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that the answer is that Visual Studio simply doesn't provide comprehensive syntax highlighting for C++.  Pity.

Comment: yes it does and its doing so every since i started using it in 1996

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors?

There's the following "Display items:"

```
User Keywords
User Types
User Types (Delegates)
User Types (Enums)
User Types (Interfaces)
User Types (Value Types)
```

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8(VS.71).aspx) details how to define the keywords. Basically create a file called `usertype.dat` with each keyword on a separate line, place it in the same directory as `devenv.exe` then restart Visual Studio.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried this in the latest versions of Visual Studio myself.*